# How to uninstall Nginx which is installed from its Source Code?

Tags: nginx

I tried to install nginx from source code.
I was watching a tutorial on youtube but in the end it didn't worked out. Hence I want to uninstall it completely.

While installing the commands used were:

1. Using wget i downloaded tar file of nginx

   vivek@skywalker:~$ wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.14.2.tar.gz
2. After extraction I added user for nginx

   vivek@skywalker:~$ sudo groupadd -r nginx

   vivek@skywalker:~$ sudo useradd -r -g nginx nginx
3. Then I wrote this in terminal

   vivek@skywalker:~$ sudo ./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx --user=nginx --group=nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-file-aio --with-http_realip_module --without-http_proxy_module

Now I want to uninstall so i wrote:

```
vivek@skywalker:~$ sudo apt-get purge nginx
```

but still when I write nginx -v it shows that nginx is installed.

```
vivek@skywalker:~$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.14.2
```

Please tell me how to completely uninstall it. Sorry, I am a newbie.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22708/how-to-uninstall-nginx-installed-from-source

Comment: @aventurin thanx man it worked :)